# How to change the style of a div if it has not id or class but the div after it does

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where a third party software provides an html template that I have no access to but they allow css changes.

Given something similar to below, such that I have the id of the second parent div but not the first parent div, is there a way I can change the background colour of the first parent div to red?

```
<div>
  <div>First div</div>
</div>
<div id='second'>
  <div>Second div</div>
</div>
```

I tried something like below but it didn't work:

```
<style>
  /* Styles for the div immediately before the second div */
  #second ~ div {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

<div>
  <div>First div</div>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <div>Second div</div>
</div>
```

Is it even possible to achieve this with only CSS?

NOTE: I can only change things based on CSS as I have not access to the HTML so I cannot add an id or use javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use selectors level 4 `:has` for this, but as of now it has limited support, currently firefox doesn't support this.

with `:has` you can do like this:

```
div:has(~#second) {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Without `:has`, you need to use some javascript logic.

check [:has support on caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-has)

```html
<style>
  div:has(~#second) {
    background-color: red;
  }

</style>

<div>
  <div>First div</div>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <div>Second div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using this selector:

```
div:has(+ #second) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

You can think of this selector as:

1. Selecting all `div`s
2. Filtering `div`s to only those that match the pattern `div + #second`, which technically will return only 1 element as `id` should be unique

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to find the element using i.e Google Developer 'Elements' Tab. If you can't do that, you might need to use JS.

```js
// Find the element of known id using getElementById
const targetDiv = document.getElementById("second");

// Get the previous child of the elements parent
const previousDiv = targetDiv.previousElementSibling;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give the first div a parent you can handle that element's CSS and it's 'div' children with `#element > child`.

```html
<style>
  #firstParent > div {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

<div id="firstParent">
  <div>First div</div>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <div>Second div</div>
</div>
```